# Import a mongoose schema in two-way makes a schema null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have two files (A and B) where I instantiate their schemas.
If I import the schema of A into B to instantiate a model and assign a ref to then do the population. It works correctly.
But if I then import the schema of B into A (doing exactly the same process), this schema gives me an undefined. It only takes the correct value when one stops consuming the other (i.e. it is not letting me consume in two-way).... I don't know why.

example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw5dL.png)